# AutoHotKey press key for 3 secs then release and press a second for 3 secs

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I want a script that i can run in the background of a game that will press <kbd>a</kbd> for 3 secs, then release and press <kbd>d</kbd> for 3 secs.

I'm not that familiar with how scripting works so I figured I'd ask for help.

It doesn't need to have a key press to start, cuz i can just double click it on my desktop to start it. i just need it to run the above loop until i stop script.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: SO is not a code writing community. You can start by reading tutorials and documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/autohotkey/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

?
A crude example

```
Loop
{
Send {a down}
Sleep 3000
Send {a up}
Send {d down}
Sleep 3000
Send {d up}
}
```